# How to fix error in Dialog after dismiss and click again?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-webview

I'm developing **webview** app, the problem in **OnJsAlert** that when i click on the **Dialog** it opens after **dismiss** it and click again it **stop** my app, for sorry i can't get the problem from **debugging**.

This is my **MainActivity.class**

```
@Override
public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, final String alertSource, final JsResult alertResult) {

    alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert);

    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);

    TextView alertMessage = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.alert_text);

    alertMessage.setText(alertSource);

    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

            alertResult.cancel();

        }


    });

    alertDialog.show();

    return true;

}
```

**Edited : *Log***

> W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
>   E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
>   W/System.err: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
>   W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:331)
>           at android.app.Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Dialog.java:1057)
>           at com.xcoder.stepview.MainActivity$4.onJsAlert(MainActivity.java:285)
>           at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.handleJsAlert(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:606)
>           at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.handleJsAlert(AwContentsClientBridge.java:73)
>           at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
>           at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00002c6d (code=-6), thread 11373 (xcoder.stepview)
>   Application terminated.

Comment: any logcat report?

Comment: Replace alertDialog.show(); with dialog.cancel();

Comment: @NoumanCh I added report.

Comment: @Benjamin didn't work for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `alertDialog` is created before `public boolean onJsAlert(...)` method called and when it's called second time you got `AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content` because of you can't use `requestWindowFeature()` with created dialog. You have to create new instance of dialog in this method or reuse global defined dialog.

Comment: @RixhionInc create new dialog inside `onJsAlert()` method  with `alertDialog = new ...` on top and keep all other code lines